# mssql - CONVERT INT value to datetime

Tags: sql-server

At this moment I'm getting records by modify datetime via:

```
WHERE modify_date >= ( SELECT DATEDIFF( s, CONVERT (datetime, ''1990-01-01'', 120), CONVERT (datetime, '+@theDate+', 120) ) )
```

where `@theDate` is for e.g.:

```
SET @theDate = '''2018-06-04 00:00:01'''
```

In column I have `BIGINT` value, e.g. `897004800` - how can I convert this value to clear datetime?

Comment: where does the 897004800 come from? is that such a user-definied function or something else that converts a date into an integer format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go the other way arround.

```
DECLARE @value BIGINT = 883612800

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, @value, '1990-01-01')
```

Your `modify_date` is the amount of seconds between your hard-coded date of 1990 and the actual modified date. If you want to display the actual modified date, just add that amount of seconds to 1990.

Answer (score 1):

If your bigint number is UNIX timestamp, yo should start from '1970-01-01':

```
DECLARE @unix_timestamp BIGINT = 883612800
, @start_from DATETIME = '1970-01-01'
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, @unix_timestamp, @start_from)
```